# My callback called before onResume and cannot change layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I really need your help here.

I have two Fragments:
1. Fragment A
2. Fragment B

One Interface
1. onSkillsSelectedListener ( method onDoneClicked )

**Fragment A implements onSkillsSelectedListener** and when "**DONE**" button is called in **Fragment B**, i call `onDoneClicked()` , and Fragment B is destroyed.

Now method onDoneClicked in Fragment A is called before even OnResume in Fragment A is called so i cannot make any changes in my Layout.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: what event to listener listen to , you handle by boolean ,if `onResume` not called, do not proceed further with listener code

Comment: listener is listening to clicked Done button in Fragment B, and when clicked i need to make some layout changed in Fragment A.

Answer (score 1):

The fragments `onResume()` or `onPause()` will be called only when the Activities `onResume()` or `onPause()` is called. They are tightly coupled to the Activity.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle

You need to find another way to implement this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes because Fragment B is from other Activity. How can i implement this in other way? How to know when button "Done" is clicked in Fragment B so i can make some changed in Fragment A?

Comment: Implement a callback or a broadcast that requests an UI update. Implementation is another question and something that you should try yourself first, even only for learning purposes. You can then even post another SO question to let us help you out with what you tried :)

Answer (score 0):

**I FIX IT**

Just changed the way i called my Fragment B 
from **replace** to **add**

So now Fragment A is not even Paused and callback is working!

Cheers!